# What's the Teichmuller representative of $2$ in $\Bbb Z_5$ - is it eventually periodic and to what does it converge?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I have that I need to start with the number I'm trying to represent $2\pmod {5^n}$ and then keep finding the next solution to $x^4-1=0$ that's equivalent to what I have already mod $5^{n+1}$

So the sequence I have so far is $2,7,57,182,2057,\ldots$

The coefficients of $5^n$ added at each step are in turn $5^0\cdot2+5^1\cdot1+5^2\cdot2+5^3\cdot1+5^4\cdot3\ldots$ so I feel like this could be written as a base $5$ sequence $\ldots31212_5$ which looks a lot like a $5$-adic number.

I wouldn't be able to prove it but Wikipedia says the fact this is a Hensel lifting process guarantees precisely one solution for each successive $n$ - so I presume $w(2)$ is an infinite sequence and a $5$-adic number.  What form does it take and to what does it converge?

The answer I'm expecting is that it has infinitely many nonzero terms, it's not eventually periodic and that it converges to some number which can only really be thought of as a $4^{th}$ root of unity, and which is different to a complex $4^{th}$ root of unity in the sense that you could add any choice of complex $4^{th}$ root to $\Bbb Z_5$ and it remain independent from $w(2)$.  Does all that sound right and is there anything else of fundamental importance to be aware of? (Apart from the premise I started with, which is that these form an alternative radix to $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$?)

Comment: That looks ok to me. I am not aware of a way to describe it better than calling it $w(2) \in \mathbb Z_5$, or saying it is the $4$-th root of unity in $\mathbb Z_5$ which is congruent to $2$, or with expansion $...31212_5$. It is definitely not periodic since otherwise it would be $\in \mathbb Q$, but it is obviously $\neq \pm 1$ which are the only roots of unity in $\mathbb Q$. There might of course be methods to compute further digits in the expansion faster than Hensel, e.g. Newton's method might work.

Comment: The one thing where you still seem to think wrongly is about how it differs from a complex $4$th root of unity. It differs because $\mathbb Z_5$ is not naturally contained in $\mathbb C$, so it does not even make sense to ask if they are "different", they just live in different worlds. In particular, you cannot "add any choice of complex $4$th root to $\mathbb Z_5$". If your algebraic structure is meant to embed into a field, there would be no space for it anyway, since there can only be four $4$-th roots of unity in any field, and there are four of them in $\mathbb Z_5$ already.

Comment: If one wanted to "construct" an embedding $\mathbb Z_5 \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$, using the axiom of choice, but at least have it explicit on the roots of unity -- then of course $w(1)=1$ must map to $1$ and $w(4)=-1$ to $-1$, and $w(2)$ and $w(3)$ must map to $i$ and $-i$ -- but you can choose freely whether $w(2)$ maps to $i$ or to $-i$ (once the choice is made, $w(3)=-w(2)$ must map to the other). The question is why would you want to do that anyway, because any "truly complex" property which distinguishes $i$ from $-i$ will most certainly not be "translatable" to $w(2)$ vs $w(3)$.

Comment: Thanks @TorstenSchoeneberg helpful. On your last point, that fits neatly with some stuff I already knew about $\Bbb C$ which I would put something like the symmetry $a+bi\mapsto a-bi$ is in a sense invisible to its vector space. The choice that $i$ sits above and $\pi$ travels anticlockwise is an arbitrary one, easily reversed in 3-dimensions by rotating the point of view of the observer by $\pi$ around the real axis. I assume the choice would therefore only become relevant once we needed to think about chirality in the context of embedding $\Bbb Z_5$ in a 3rd dimension.

Comment: In fact, @TorstenSchoeneberg, Newton’s method works very well, and as you’d expect, adds twice as many places of accuracy in each iteration.

Comment: Since it seemed you were partly interested in representations, an alternate form that I don't see people mention much (which requires some care) is we can write $\omega(x)=x*(x^{p-1})^{\bar 1}$ where $\bar 1 = ...1111 = \frac{1}{1-p}$. It might be tempting to think this means $x*(x^{p-1})^\frac{1}{1-p}=x^{1+\frac{p-1}{1-p}} = 1$ but being more careful we have $x^{p-1}=1 \mod p$ and p-adic integer powers of $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ remain there, and so $\omega(x)=x \mod p$. It's a fun exercise to show that it obeys the usual properties like $\omega(xy)=\omega(x)\omega(y)$ and $\omega(x)^{p-1}=1$.

Comment: Thanks @Merosity this will be helpful because one of the tasks I plan to do will involve spending some time looking at how algebra is preserved in p-adic numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are converging to is a square root of $-1$.  The $5$-adic integers have a bit of notoriety because $5$ is the smallest $p$ for which $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has such roots.

Because $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ has Unique Factorisation, any solution of $x^4-1=0$ which is the polynomial you use to construct this equation must solve one of the factor equations $x-1=0,x+1=0,x^2+1=0$.  Clearly your representation with a $\bmod 5$ residue of $2$ misses the first two equations and so must solve the third.  The equation $x^2+1=0$ also will have a root ending with $3$ in $5$-adics, which is of course the additive inverse of your root ending with $2$.

We might be tempted to call one root $i$ and the other $-i$.  But no such identification is inherently built into the numbers because the $5$-adic roots live in a different domain from the complex numbers.  What we can do, however, is use either of these roots in place of $i$ or $-i$ and thus "map" complex number relationships into $5$-adic relationships.  For instance:

$(1\pm i)^2=2×(\pm i)$

$[1+(...212)]^2=2×(...212)$ *or* $[1+(...233)]^2=2×(...233)$

As a final note, the question asks whether the representation for this square root of $-1$ eventually becomes periodic.  That answer is "no".  The number $-1$ is not a rational square, and only rational numbers have periodic $p$-adic representations.

Comment: Good answer. The process of taking successive $p$-th powers is rather slow, but it works.

Comment: Hey! Nice downvote! Would be even better if you could suggest an improvement or answer yourself!

Comment: Well, @OscarLanzi, I’ve calculated that square root of $-1$ in many ways, including using the Binomial Series for $\sqrt{1+z}$ and Newton-Raphson, and believe me, Newton-Raphson has all the others beaten by miles (kilometers).